# Handsontable not scrolling properly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angular-material, handsontable

I am currently having an issue with handsontable on Chrome. What appears is that the table is scrollable, but the values and row headings are not updating. The situation can be seen from the below pictures.

#### Not Scrolled

[image: Original]

#### Scrolled to Right and Down

[image]

As you can see, the scrolling takes place, but the values do not update. I should note, that this behavior only happens on Chrome. On Firefox and Safari, the table works as expected.

So more information about my environment.

- Using `Handsontable 0.28.0`
- Also using AngularJS and Angular Material

The code that I used to create this example is as follows

```
var Handsontable = require('handsontable');
// This function finds a div I am using, removes its contents, and then creates the table.
$scope.setSheet = function() {
   
    var elementID = "shreadsheet-" + $scope.tabData.id;
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    element.innerHTML = '';
    var readonlyArr = $scope.tabData.sheetHeaders.map(function() {
        return {readOnly : true};
    });
    var hot = new Handsontable(element, {
        data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(1000, 1000),
        colWidths: 47,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true
    });
};
```

I compiled this code using the following command I found in the docs at the Handsontable github page.

```
SheetController_work.js -o SheetController.js -r moment -r pikaday -r zeroclipboard -r numbro
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem on Google Chrome, or does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this problem magically went away. The things that happened in the time that I noticed that this problem exists and the time that it magically fixed itself are as follows. You may want to try some of these if you experience this problem.

- Restarted Computer (didn't work by itself)
- Turned off localhost server from terminal and navigated to different directory.
- Quit terminal.
- Quit Google Chrome

#### EDIT with proper solution

I removed the paramater `variableRowHeights: false` and everything works now.